# Change background color with button in HTML page (how to use more than 1 color)

Tags: html

So far I can get my background color on my page to change when I click the button but only to the 1 set color.

I want to be able to keep clicking on the button and get a different color each time or at least a handful of different preset colors.

This is what I have just now.

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Change Color</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{   
document.body.style.backgroundColor= "green";
}
</script>
```

Comment: There are different ways to implement it, partly depending on what you want. Some answers here assume that you want random colors, which is a rather random assumption. You can set up e.g. a selection between given colors using a `select` element or let the user select a color from a color picker (on supporting browsers) using `<input type=color>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10)

function myFunction()
{
switch(randomnumber)
{
case 1:
  document.body.style.backgroundColor= "green";
  break;
case 2:
  document.body.style.backgroundColor= "blue";
  break;
case 3:
  document.body.style.backgroundColor= "red";
  break;
...
etc
...


default:
  code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
}   

}
</script>
```

**This function should work. First generate a random number between 1 and 10, and just have switch with the changing**

Answer (score 1):

This is a example, of what you want.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
    var colorIndex = 0;
    function changeColor() {
        var col = document.getElementById("body");
        if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
            colorIndex = 0;
        }
        col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
        colorIndex++;
    }
</script>
    <body id='body'>
    <button onclick="changeColor();">Change color</button>
    </body>
</html
```

What I do here was:
1.Give `<body>` an `id`
2.Make button that call function on click.
3.Call the body by using it id (`document.getElementById('body')`) and make it change the background color (`document.getElementById('body').style.background = colors[colorIndex]`)
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function myFunction(){   
    var colors = ["green", "black","yellow"],
    selectedColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]
    $("body").css("background-color", selectedColor);
}
```

You can use whatever color you want to use. Just put them into array. You can also use the color codes as well like `"#F4F5F3"`.

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C7d3E/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a random color generator:

```
function get_random_color() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

and then pass the colour generated as your background colour.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use something like this. It have a soft-transition animations with any colors you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
setColor();
function setColor(){
     var colors=["#33ccff", "#ffff99","#cc6699"];
      var color =Math.floor(Math.random() * (colors.length));
  
    $('body').toggleClass('clicked');
    setTimeout(function(){
     $('.clicked').css("background-color", colors[color]);
    $('body').removeClass('clicked');
    }, 200)  
  }
  
   $('#gen').on("click", function(){
    setColor();
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: grey;
  transition:background-color 0.5s ease;
}
.clicked {
  background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="gen">Generate</button>
</body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function black() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="black"
}

function blue() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue"
}

function fuchsia() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="fuchsia"
}

function green() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="green"
}

function orange() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="#c44000"
}

function purple() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="purple"
}

function red() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"
}

function oil() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="#808000"
}

function white() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="white"
}

function brown() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="brown"
}

function yellow() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="yellow"
}

function lgreen() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="#00ff00"
}
```

```html
<form>
 <input type="button" style="background-color:black" hover="background-color:#3e8e41" value="    " name="B1" onclick="black()" />
 <input type="button" style="background-color:blue" value="    " name="B2" onclick="blue()" />
 <input type="button" style="background-color:#ff00ff" value="    " name="B3" onclick="fuchsia()" />
 <input type="button" style="background-color:green" value="    " name="B4" onclick="green()" />
 <input type="button" style="background-color:#808000" value="    " name="B7" onclick="oil()" />
 <input type="button" style="background-color:purple" value="    " name="B5" onclick="purple()" />
 <input type="button" style="background-color:red" value="    " name="B6" onclick="red()" />
 <input type="button" style="background-color:#c44000" value="    " name="B8" onclick="orange()" />
 <input type="button" style="background-color:white" value="    " name="B9" onclick="white()" />
 <input type="button" style="background-color:brown" value="    " name="B10" onclick="brown()" />
 <input type="button" style="background-color:yellow" value="    " name="B11" onclick="yellow()" />
 <input type="button" style="background-color:#00ff00" value="    " name="B12" onclick="lgreen()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please format your code to be more readable. This is horrible

Comment: sorry. just did it.

Comment: You just doubled your code. Please [edit] and correct it.

Comment: Aladdin, I edited your code now. Please compare our two versions and see how correctly formatted code should look like. Your code did not follow any style or consistency. If you're new to programming, I highly encourage you to read this Wikipedia Article on [Indentation Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style).

Answer (score 0):

you can change the colors of your button with bootstrap, through this;

Change Color for red
Change Color for blue
Change Color for green
Change Color for yellow

Answer (score 0):

```
var isBlack = 0;
function changeBackground() {
  if (isBlack == 0){
    var backgr = document.getElementById('bg').style="background-color:#52b0d6; color:white;";
        document.getElementById('selectback').innerHTML="CHANGE WEB BACKGROUND COLOR... (#2)";
        document.getElementById('selectback').style="background-color:#464141;";
        isBlack=true;
  isBlack= 1;
  }

  else{
    var dftBg = document.getElementById('bg').style="background-image:url('issets/images/backgrnd.jpg'); color:white;";
        document.getElementById('selectback').innerHTML="RESTORE TO DEFAULT BACKGROUND COLOR... (#3)";
        document.getElementById('selectback').style="background-color:black;";
        document.getElementById('centered').style="background-color:#464141;";
        isBlack=true;
  isBlack= 0;
  }
}
```

**[You can see the full project on github](https://github.com/Dom58/WEB-Background-Changes-Trick)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to define the set of colors, or even a pair of colors (ex: background color + text color) here's something that worked for me:

*The example shows setting multiple colors, but I add more detail on changing a single color at the bottom*

```js
var background = document.querySelector("body");
var text = document.querySelector("h1")
var colorButton = document.querySelector(".myClass");
colorButton.addEventListener("click", colorChange);

function colorChange() {

  var colorSet = [{
      background: "#f7c5cc",
      text: "#cc313d"
    },
    {
      background: "#000",
      text: "#fff"
    },
    {
      background: "#fff",
      text: "#000"
    },
    {
      background: "#234e70",
      text: "#fbf8be"
    },
    {
      background: "#fcedda",
      text: "#ee4e34"
    },
  ];

  //to have the colors come in a random order
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorSet.length);

  //and then you would change each element individually
  background.style.backgroundColor = colorSet[random].background;
  text.style.color = colorSet[random].text;

  // if you wanted to just change the background, replace "var colorSet" with an array like this:
  //var colorSet = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "#f7c5cc"];

  // and select the color like this:
  //background.style.backgroundColor = colorSet[random];

}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1> Hi </h1>
  <button class="myClass">click me to change colors</button>
</body>

</html>
```

The challenge with this method is that sometimes you'll get the same color back to back (since they're selected randomly) so it will look like the click didn't do anything. AZDeveloper's answer avoids this, but the colors will always be in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a very old question.
But I have been trying to do the same thing,
and this is what I found

This Code has the possibility to generate any color from the entire html color spectrum

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> color changer </title>

  <script>
    function color() {
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);

      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Click button to get random color</h1>
  <BR />
  <INPUT type="button" value="Change color" onclick="color()">

</body>

</html>
```

Math.random() is used to generate a random number between 0 and 255.
Three such variables are used to set background color using `rgb( , , );`